# Error in result_create when using sqldf with a "From" variable

Tags: r, sqldf

```
result = sqldf("select * 
           FROM ABC_ocean 
           LEFT JOIN lookup_date 
           ON ABC_ocean.departure_date_local BETWEEN lookup_date.From AND lookup_date.To")
```

I am trying to join two databases on date that falls between a range using the above code. I get the following msg:

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "From": syntax error
```

Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

`str(lookup_date)`:

[image: Lookup_date]

`str(ABC_ocean)`:

[image]

Comment: Nope putting everything in one line did not work. I also made sure all the fields are same format i.e. Date

Comment: It seems to be a SQL syntax error. Try running the same SQL statement on the database you may figure out what is wrong. I suspect using `From` as a column name without quotes could be a problem as it is a SQL keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FROM` is a reserved word. It's not the first instance of `FROM` that's an issue but the column name `From`. If that's really the name it'll need to be quoted. Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ABC_ocean 
LEFT JOIN lookup_date 
    ON ABC_ocean.departure_date_local BETWEEN lookup_date.`From` AND lookup_date.To
```

Comment: Thank you, sir ! Column names were the issue. Fixed it :)